# Is it possible to get the value of USE TOUCHID FOR iPhone unlock in default settings

Tags: ios, objective-c, authentication, settings, touch-id

Is it possible to Access Default settings > TouchID & Passcode > iPhone Unlock toggle value.

[image]

Comment: What do u need? U can get Touch ID is Configured or supported for device or not  using iOS SDK...!

Comment: No i just want to know the status of the toggle button in default settings >  TouchID & Passcode > iPhone Unlock. Are we able to get that data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, it's not possible.

Answer (score 2):

NO.  there is no way to know if user has opted for using TouchID for Unlocking phone.

There is method canEvaluatePolicy: error:

But this tells you if TouchId is configured / Enabled or Not Configured/Not Enabled. If you want to check for Availability of touch Id for your app, you can use canEvaluatePolicy: error:

> -(void)canEvaluatePolicy {
>       LAContext *context = [[LAContext alloc] init];
>       __block  NSString *message; 
>       NSError *error; 
>       BOOL success;
>
> ```
> // test if we can evaluate the policy, this test will tell us if Touch ID is available and enrolled 
> success = [context canEvaluatePolicy: <BR>LAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics error:&error]; 
> if (success) { 
>     message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Touch ID is available"]; 
> } 
> else { 
>     message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Touch ID is not available"]; 
> } 
>
>
> [super printMessage:message inTextView:self.textView];
> ```
>
> }

you can find fully working code from developer.apple.com website:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/KeychainTouchID/Listings/KeychainTouchID_AAPLLocalAuthenticationTestsViewController_m.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you would want to know that however, you can always check if the device supports TouchID and if it has been setup by the user. You do this by creating an `LAContext` (Local Authentication Context) and calling the function `canEvaluatePolicy:error:`. That is all I think you can find out about the TouchID settings on a given iPhone through an app. I hope this helps a little :)